# Python - Sum a column where each row is less than two other columns

Tags: python

I have many columns from an imported csv file that I am analyzing in combinations of 3 (where 'abc' = 'cba' = 'bac' so only one combination of those used).

My objective is to sum the value of each column into 3 variables where the row is the lowest between the 3

```
for s1 in range(15, 134):
  for s2 in range(s1 + 1, 135):
    for s3 in range(s2 + 1, 136):
     for r in range(2, 27041):
        if data[r][s1] < data[r][s2] and data[r][s1] < data[r][s3]:
            s1M = s1M + float(data[r][s1])
            s1C = s1C + float(data[r][12])
        elif data[r][s2] < data[r][s1] and data[r][s2] < data[r][s3]:
            s2M = s2M + float(data[r][s2])
            s2C = s2C + float(data[r][12])
        else:
            s3M = s3M + float(data[r][s3])
            s3C = s3C + float(data[r][12])
```

So I need s1M to be the sum of column s1 where it has the lowest value per row, s2M where s2 has the lowest value per row and s3M where s3 has the lowest value per row.

Whilst this is fairly quick I'd like to know if there is a quicker way to do it without looping each row.

In addition, there are 3 other variables that need to be the total of column 12 where each row in s1, s2 and s3 column has the lowest value.

Example

```
Cube    s1  s2   s3
156     1   6    3 
134     2   5    4 
105     3   4    5 
3       4   3    6 
744     5   2    1 
89      6   1    2
```

Comparing these columns I would hope to have the following output

```
s1M = 6 (rows 1, 2 and 3)
s2M = 5 (rows 4 and 6)
s3M = 2 (row 5)

s1C = 395
s2C = 91
s3C = 744
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you share an example of data and desired output?

Comment: And why are you not using data computing libraries like `numpy` or `pandas`?

Comment: I've updated the question with my desired output.

Comment: As for not using numpy and pandas, well this is day 1 of my learning python, I guess I have a while to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example data, this approach seems okay:

```
cube = [156,134,105,3,744,89]
s1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
s2 = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
s3 = [3,4,5,6,1,2]

data = zip(s1, s2, s3)

sM = {0: 0,
      1: 0,
      2: 0}

sC = {0: 0,
      1: 0,
      2: 0}

for i, row in enumerate(data):
    low = min(row)
    sM[row.index(low)] += low
    sC[row.index(low)] += cube[i]
```